# TBitmap->LoadFromStream failed with Win XP

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe3

I'm using C++ Builder XE3 to develop a graph editor. All of the editing and drawing capabilities are made in a DLL that is loaded by the end user applications.
To store information about the available graph objects I use a SQLite database. That database contains BMP icons that are loaded into a TImageList at run-time.

Everything works fine with Win-7, Win-8 and Win-vista but with Win-XP a "Floating point division by 0" occurs when loading the bitmap. I use a temporary memory stream to load the blob from the database and then load it into a temporary TBitmap which is used to add the new icon into the final TImageList.

Here is the function used to do so...

```
void TIcons::AddMaskedBitmap( TImageList *ptImgList, unsigned char *pucIcon, unsigned int uiSize )
{
    TMemoryStream *ptMemStream;

    //  Use a memory stream
    ptMemStream = new TMemoryStream();
    ptMemStream->Write( pucIcon, uiSize );
    ptMemStream->Position = 0;//Seek( ( int )0, ( unsigned short )soBeginning );

    //  Load using the cached bmp object
    m_ptBmp->Transparent = true;
#warning "floatting point division by 0 error with WinXP"
    m_ptBmp->LoadFromStream( ptMemStream ); //  floatting point division by 0 error with WinXP
//  m_ptBmp->LoadFromFile( ".\\d.bmp" );    //  works

    //  Create a mask
    m_ptBmpMask->Assign( m_ptBmp );
    m_ptBmpMask->Canvas->Brush->Color = m_ptBmp->TransparentColor;
    m_ptBmpMask->Monochrome = true;

    //  Add it to the list
    ptImgList->Add( m_ptBmp, m_ptBmpMask );

    //  Free mem
    m_ptBmp->FreeImage();
    m_ptBmpMask->FreeImage();
    delete ptMemStream;
}
```

I've traced the TBitmap::LoadFromStream function and the exception occurs in the CreateDIBSection function.

To make sure the loaded bitmap files are saved using the right encoding I've tried to load them using the TBitmap::LoadFromFile function and it works fine, so I think there's something wrong with the TBitmap::LoadFromStream function but I can't figure out what !

If anyone has an idea...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoadFromFile` is implemented by creating a file stream, and passing that to `LoadFromStream`. This, if the contents of your memory stream are the same as the contents of the file, then the call to `LoadFromStream` will succeed.

Thus the only sane conclusion is that the contents of the memory stream are invalid in some way.

Comment: @<david hefferman>, pucIcon refers to a .bmp file, I'm sure of this. The database used on Win-XP is the same file as the one used on Win-7 and the d.bmp file has been created by extracting the bitmap from the database. here is the three first bytes of the memory stream "BMö" => bitmap header magic word.

Comment: Try this then. Call SaveToFile on the memory stream. And then call LoadFromFile on the bitmap. I predict that you'll get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap stored into the database is encoded using the BITMAPV4HEADER structure which is supposed to be supported since Win95/NT4 but there's something wrong.

It works fine if I encode the bitmap using the BITMAPINFOHEADER structure which is an older version of bitmap encoding which does not contain color space information.

Comment: In other words, my answer was accurate.

Comment: your answer made me realize that the extracted bitmap file "d.bmp" has been converted by the database explorer software I use so it was slightly different from the bitmap stored into the database but pucIcon does refer to a .bmp file.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I could not help you.

Comment: No you did, you've shown me a trail to follow ! But I've posted another distinct answer cause if someone has the same issue he might think that the problem was because the file stored in the database is not a bitmap but it is, but not with the right encoding. So your answer really helped me.

Comment: Your answer isn't an answer to your question. It's the solution to your problem. There's no way anyone other than you could know how your database was storing the information. I don't see the purpose of your answer. Anyway, never mind.

Comment: Ho god!are you offended cause I didn't validate your answer ??? I thought stackoverflow was a website to find solutions to issues !!!!

Comment: You seem a little ungrateful. I gave you an accurate answer to your question and told you how to debug your problem. You then claim that the true answer is the one that comes from following my advice and debugging your local environment. I repeat, you answer is not an answer to the question that you asked. It is the solution to your problem. SO is not a website to find solutions to your problem. It's a site to get answers for questions. Nothing in your question mentions bitmap headers.

Comment: don't cry I'll validate your great answer.

Comment: Don't be like that. You came here looking for help.

Comment: You're right I did, and I told you that you helped me and I thanked you but you're still upset. I do think it can be very helpful to someone else to know that Builder and Delphi can't load bitmap files with color space encoded it it (even if it was not my initial question this is what I found out). we might close this topic this website is not here for this. thanks again for your help.

Comment: Normally you would vote if an answer helps, and accept the best answer.

Comment: Yes, the info about v5 headers is interesting, but nobody's going to find it in a seemingly unrelated question. It would make a good question in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out a solution that works for me.

My problem was that software that was developed on Win7, when running on XP was throwing the division by 0 error when loading one of my BMPs.

It turns out that the problematic BMP was saved using Win7 Paint (other BMPs that were ok were saved from Gimp).

All I needed to do to fix it was to open this BMP on XP Paint and save it from there.

Comment: This is due to what version of the BITMAPINFOHEADER section your paint program uses. See my post where I explain the solution.